# mysql how to convert varchar(10) to TIMESTAMP?

Tags: mysql, timestamp, varchar

I have stored all the date into my database as `varchar(10)`, now I want to converse them into TIMESTAMP.

When I run sql

```
ALTER TABLE  `demo3` CHANGE  `date`  `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
```

it alert:

```
#1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '1320534000' for column 'date' at row 1
```

BTW, All my date formart are 10 digital number.

Comment: What format are your strings that represent dates in?

Comment: @Anthony Grist, `1320534000` they are transfer from `strtotime()`

Comment: @fishman I did not know you are fans of Converse :p

Comment: @fishman please provide example date value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first change the timestamp to datetime and then can change the type of column.

```
ALTER TABLE `demo3` MODIFY COLUMN `date` varchar(25);

UPDATE `demo3` SET `date`= FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`);

ALTER TABLE  `demo3` CHANGE  `date`  `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
```

Comment: That's cool - I thought you needed an intermediate column to transform into. I'll try this later - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a new column with the type you want, then update the table, converting the string to number for each row in an update statement.

So Add your new timestamp column with a default of NULL

Then run something similar to:

```
UPDATE demo3 SET new_timestamp = CONVERT(date, signed)
```

(You may need to try converting from unix timestamp and back again - see http://kitt.hodsden.org/mysql/converting_to_mysqls_timestamp_from_int11)

Which should push the integers into the timestamp column.

Then get rid of the original date column and rename the timestamp column.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to convert that unix timestamp format with the FROM_UNIXTIME function.